# Using MvcHtmlString with jQuery templates - what's the correct razor syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-templates, mvchtmlstring

I have such jQuery template:

```
<script id="msgTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li><span style="color:Black"><strong>${user.name}</strong> (${datetime})</span><br/><span>${richMessage}</span></li>
</script>
```

And I use it in such way:

```
        $.post("/GetMessages", null, function (data, s) {

            if (data.messages) {
                $('#msgTmpl').tmpl(data.messages).appendTo('#chatList');
            }

        ... and so on.
```

**richMessage can contain HTML tags.**

I want it to be interpreted as HTML not to be displayed as sequence of tags...

I know MVCHtmlString.Create has to be used but I can not figure out the correct syntax.

I also tried to use [AllowHtml] attribute on richMessage property but with no success.

My problem is: how to use MvcHtmlString.Create to allow MVC display richMessage correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `{{html richMessage}}` instead of `${richMessage}`. Your problem lies with the fact that `${}` encodes values by default.

Comment: Thanks a million, you saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`{{html property}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/) syntax of jQuery templates.  This is simialr to `@Html.Raw` on the MVC side.

```
<span>{{html richMessage}}</span>
```

This will output the contents of the `richMessage` property into the `span` tag without escaping the HTML.